# ActionScript 3 Syntax Errors

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm new to AS3 and this site. I'm using a tutorial from http://asgamer.com/2009/as3-flash-games-for-beginners-scores-huds-and-user-interface to create my own version of shooting game. The tutorial comes with 1 enemy and 1 game level and I'm trying to add more enemies and levels.

Here's the original Engine.as coding from the tutorial:

```
package com.asgamer.basics1 
{   import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;

public class Engine extends MovieClip
{

    private var numStars:int = 80;
    public static var enemyList:Array = new Array();
    private var ourShip:Ship;

    private var scoreHUD:ScoreHUD;

    public function Engine() : void
    {
        ourShip = new Ship(stage);
        ourShip.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        ourShip.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        ourShip.addEventListener("hit", shipHit, false, 0, true);
        stage.addChild(ourShip);


        scoreHUD = new ScoreHUD(stage);
        stage.addChild(scoreHUD);

        for (var i:int = 0; i < numStars; i++)
        {
            stage.addChildAt(new Star(stage), stage.getChildIndex(ourShip));
        }

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);

    }

    private function loop(e:Event) : void
    {
        if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 90) == 5)
        {
            var enemy:Stinger = new Stinger(stage, ourShip);

            enemy.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removeEnemy, false, 0, true);
            enemy.addEventListener("killed", enemyKilled, false, 0, true);
            enemyList.push(enemy);
            stage.addChild(enemy);
        }   
    }

    private function enemyKilled(e:Event)
    {
        scoreHUD.updateKills(1);
        scoreHUD.updateScore(e.currentTarget.points);           
    }

    private function removeEnemy(e:Event)
    {
        enemyList.splice(enemyList.indexOf(e.currentTarget), 1);
    }

    private function shipHit(e:Event)
    {
        scoreHUD.updateHits(1);
    }


}
}
```

For enemies, I've created another enemy named Stinger2 and added it under the first enemy loop as below but I got error 1021 and 5000.

```
    private function loop(e:Event) : void
    {
        if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 90) == 5)
        {
            var enemy:Stinger = new Stinger(stage, ourShip);

            enemy.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removeEnemy, false, 0, true);
            enemy.addEventListener("killed", enemyKilled, false, 0, true);
            enemyList.push(enemy);
            stage.addChild(enemy);
        }   
    }

    private function loop(e:Event) : void
    {
        if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 90) == 5)
        {
            var enemy:Stinger2 = new Stinger2(stage, ourShip);

            enemy.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removeEnemy, false, 0, true);
            enemy.addEventListener("killed", enemyKilled, false, 0, true);
            enemyList.push(enemy);
            stage.addChild(enemy);
        }   
    }
```

For levels, I want to create 3 different levels. The first level comes with Stinger only, the second comes with Stinger2 only and the final level comes with both Stinger and Stinger2. There is also a score system from the tutorial, the below coding is from the tutorial, it controls the chance of enemy spawns:

```
       if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) == 5
```

I tried to change it to:

```
       if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) == 5 && scoreHUD(value:Number) < 10000)
```

so Stinger only spawns when player's score is below 10000 (level 1) but then I got a error 1084. So how do I add multiple enemies to the array and how to make these enemies spawn between specific scores?

Answer (score 1):

Error 1021 means you have two functions with the same name (`loop`), this is not allowed for obvious reasons.

Error 5000 is sometimes ambiguous, it usually happens when you have other problems in your code.

> Error 5000: The class 'myClass' must subclass 'flash.display.MovieClip' since it is linked to a library symbol of that type

You should take a look at your library in flash to make sure you have the correct base classes declared.

Error 1084 is just a simple syntax error, you are missing a `)` in your `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the enemies problem, but I still can't fix the level problem.